# Is it possible to display progress during the execution of a Visual Studio TestMethod?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

Is there a way I can show the progress of a single TestMethod In Visual Studio 2008 ?

Within a set of unit tests, I have a single TestMethod that runs for a very, very long time - normally it will take between 30 and 60 minutes.  I've set the Timeout using the [Timeout] attribute, no problem there.  But I'd like to be able to get a visual indication of progress of the test.

I know the Test Results window gives a visual progress update of all the test methods.  What I want is a visual progress update of a single method.  In a WinForms app I would popup a ProgressBar control.  In a console app, I would position the cursor and display a status message.  But this is a unit test.  I can write to the TestContext, but that window is not viewable until the test completes.

---

**EDIT**: I know there is a way to do it; it's all just software, so there is always a way.  But what is a simple, practical way?

One way to do it is to create a TestMethodProgressMonitor.exe app, which reads from a named pipe, and updates a progress bar based on the messages that come through the pipe.  The TestMethod can shellExec the TestMethodProgressMonitor.exe, then write to the named pipe.  When finished, maybe there is a well-known shutdown command that the TestMethod sends to the TestMethodProgressMonitor.exe  app.

Another option is to construct the TestMethodProgressMonitor.exe as a COM server, and the TestMethod can use COM (DCOM) to update a hosted progress bar within the app.

Another option is to use the user32.dll SendMessage() method to send a WM_COPYDATA message to the monitor app. This is sometimes done for remote control of apps.

Those are some of the possibilities. Before I set about building one of them, I'd like to know if there is a simpler way.

Comment: a unit test that takes that long, is not a unit test per definition. What causes it to take so long?

Comment: It's a test of creating a ZIP64 file; The test encrypts a set of files that result in a zipfile larger than 4gb.  Then the zipfile gets updated, and saved again (twice). The code is about 5 lines surrounded by a loop.  But there's lots and lots of I/O and lots of DEFLATE.  Are you really saying that the definition of unit test includes a time limit?  What's the time limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just start a GUI thread with a Window that has the progressbar.

Here's a snippet to get you started.  It simply pops up MyProgressWindow in another thread (rather than another process).

```
[ClassInitialize()]
static public void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
    start_app_in_gui_thread();
}

static Thread t;

private static void start_app_in_gui_thread()
{
    t = new Thread(() => {
        var w = new MyProgressWindow();
        var app = new App();
        app.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
        app.Run(w);
    });
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: Doh! What does that mean?  Whadaya mean "start a GUI thread"?

Answer (score 1):

For my long running tests I use the Trace APIs to attach a trace listener (DbgView or something custom).

Makes it dead simple to see what's going on without having to jump through any hoops.

This isn't going to give you a progress bar experience (though you could write one pretty easily).

Comment: Great! By the way, using System.Diagnostics.Debug even lets you see the output in the Output window

Answer (score 1):

I met the same requirement, but any new file or executable sounds too much to me: I am writing unit test, not an application. Following code writes progress into Debug Output window:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ProgressTest()
    {
        int nLastWritten = -1, nTotal = 10000;

        for (int i = 0; i < nTotal; i++)
        {
            int nProgress = 100 * i / nTotal;
            if (nProgress > nLastWritten)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Progress: " + nProgress + "%");
                nLastWritten = nProgress;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the easiest way, but this is what I did.  I hacked up a class that does WM_COPYDATA send and receive.  It's a transceiver. This allows one Windows app to communicate with another, on the same machine, fairly low latency.  I packaged it as an assembly.

Then I built a winforms app (UnitTestProgressMonitor.exe) that creates one of those transceivers, and updates its UI based on the messages it receives.  The messages are just strings.  This is what they do:

- bars 3 - The UI creates and displays 3 progress bars
- pb 0 max 100 - sets the max for progress bar #0 to 100
- pb 0 value 28 - sets the value for progress bar #0 to 28
- stop  - exit.

Then, within the [TestMethod], I shellexec the UnitTestProgressMonitor.exe, then create a transceiver and send the app messages.

The test code sends "bars 3" to the progress monitor app, to tell it to create 3 progress bars.  The 1st one tracks the 7 steps in the test. The 2nd progress bar gauges progress on the zip file; each entry in the file is a step along the bar.  The 3rd bar is the progress for an individual entry. Some of these are multi-gigabyte files, so compressing them can take a while.  During the execution of the test, the test sends a "pb 0 step" or whatever, at the appropriate times. These messages cause the progress bars to update.  At the end of the test, the test code sends a "stop" to the monitor app. In response to that, the progress monitor app disappears.  The test ends.

[Unit Test Progress Monitor http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/45b4979b92.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/45b4979b92.jpg)